# CustomTkinter set value in textbox after calculation

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I have a problem with my code.
im beginner and i search how to display a calculation result in a textBox in CustomTkinter.

here is my code :

```
        self.sidebar_button_1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.tabview.tab("TEST"), text="Calcul", command=self.test_calculator(self.input_text_longueur, self.input_text_largeur, self.input_text_hauteur))
    self.sidebar_button_1.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=20, pady=10)

def test_calculator(self, long: int, larg: int, haut: int):
    long = self.input_text_longueur.get("1.0")
    larg = self.input_text_largeur.get("1.0")
    haut = self.input_text_hauteur.get("1.0")
    self.calcul = ((larg + haut)* 2 + long)
    self.input_text_dimension = self.calcul
```

Can you help me for resolve this issue please :D?
And in my console when i add a print at the end of method test_calculator.

```
print("test")
```

as soon as i run the script it appears instantly

[image: Picture explication]

I want the 3 values in the inputs to display the result when the calculate button is pressed with the calculation done above

i try this but i dont working :D

```
def test_calculator(self, long: int, larg: int, haut: int):
    long = self.input_text_longueur.get("1.0")
    larg = self.input_text_largeur.get("1.0")
    haut = self.input_text_hauteur.get("1.0")
    self.calcul = ((larg + haut)* 2 + long)
    self.input_text_dimension.insert(END, self.calcul)
    print("test")
```

Comment: Can you give me the whole code ? I will try to fix it.

Comment: It is better to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for but, in CustomTkinter you can use the insert method to insert something in a entry / textbox:

```
entry.insert(END, self.calcul)
```

If your code doesn't recognize "END" please add the following line :

```
from customtkinter import *
```

I hope it's an answer for your question, if not please reply I would be glad to answer you.

Good luck!